# How are the Sith Inquisitors named?

Tags: character, star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

There are a few Sith Inquisitors introduced in the TV show *Obi-Wan Kenobi*, two of whom are named the Third Sister and the Fifth Brother. During a verbal confrontation, the Grand Inquisitor says to the Third Sister:

> You are the least of us.

This implies the Third Sister is ranked lower than the Grand Inquisitor and the Fifth Brother.

Is there any explanation regarding how the Inquisitors are named? Isn't it logical for the Third Sister to be more senior than the Fifth Brother?

Comment: The Third Sister *is* ranked lower than the Grand Inquisitor. He's called the *Grand* Inquisitor for a reason. I see your point about her and the Fifth Brother, though.

Comment: They sometimes actually have "other" names too. For instance The Third Sister is also named "Reva" and out of universe she is named for Revan from the old EU. The Second sister was formerly Trilla Suduri as many of the Inquistors are "turned" (often tortured) Jedi...As for ranking, I don't think the heirarchy is established, except that TGI is at the top of the Inquisitor food chain. He was once a Temple Guard in the Jedi Order (per Rebels) and Temple Guard are meant to anonomous, hence his name.former name is unknown.

Comment: I would also like to point out that at least in terms of Sidious' methods of creating dark side apprentices and/or acolytes, his methods are usually about making people suffer greatly and pitting his prospects against each other to get the "best" one. It might be possible that these words are more about following suit with Sidious' methods by "degrading" the Third Sister to make her stronger with the dark side, than it is about her true status. However, it's also possible that TGI may feel jealous/threatened by her, because perhaps she has force abilities they do not...

Comment: and as TGI will come to know, there are things greater than death when you fail!

Comment: I assume the number is more likely an indicator of the *order they became Inquisitors*. If it was a rank, it should change once a higher-numbered Inquisitor dies, but there has been no indication of this.

Comment: Having just watched Part 2, it seems clear to me that when the Grand Inquisitor calls the Third Sister "the least of us", he's referring to her social standing *before* joining the Inquisitorius, not her actual rank within the organisation itself.